# Will my brother's CoC village be affected if I start a new game on my account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have this old Clash of Clans account here on my iPod using my brother's Game Center account. When I stop playing CoC my brother will continue to do so, on his iPod, using the same account. Now I want to play CoC again with my own GC account, but when I load CoC it loads my old CoC village. I want to create a new CoC account but I'm afraid that my brother's account will be deleted.

The question is: Will my brother's account be deleted if I start a new one even if I have a new account of GC?

Note: we have different devices and different accounts in Game Center, but my CoC loads my brother's account which is the old save data in my iPod.

Answer (score 2):

No. *Your* village is linked to *your* account. If you create a new village on your own account, his account won't be affected, and so his village will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, but I have this another problem how can I create a new CoC account

Answer (score 0):

basically for one Game Center/Google account you can have only one COC account,if you want to play COC from scratch with your account you can uninstall and re install your coc and log in using your new Game Center/Google account ..your brothers COC account will not get deleted untill you use his Game Center Account and play from scratch